How can I fix this paint damage best?
I had a baby gate up at the top of my stairs and recently took it down. It took the paint with it.
 
What is the best way to fix this so it will match the texturing?

Do you still have the baby gate? It may be possible to shave the paint off the mounting tip with a sharp razor blade and glue the paint back to the wall with white glue.
Get the glue under the peeled-up edges too, then use a block masked with clear packing tape and a press-fit curtain rod as a clamp across the passage while the glue dries.
If you get everything aligned right, you may get only a hairline crack where the paint was pulled off.

That looks like orange peel texture out of a can to me.  I would probably take a sharp blade and cut around the "hole" to get edges that aren't peeled away, then fill with joint compound.  Sand flat, then respray and repaint.  (Obvs test the can texture on a piece of scrap first.)  The painting part might be tough, just matching the color and sheen.  You might need to repaint the whole wall.
